# Sandbox environment iPhone In-Purchase

Tags: iphone, xcode, in-app-purchase

i am develop my firts app whit App-Purchase and have some trouble try to up the sandbox environment using xcode.. so i have..

1. Xcode 3.2.5 and 4.2.1....
2. I create the account test in itunes connect..
3. I have severals codes from how i pur storekit.. any works...
4. i send a new release from an app, in this release i activate an item, but this release was rejected because in "itunes" not found the item for buy...

I use all codes and when debug in the device the app try to up the storekit.. but not found some "item"....

I supose that i have some probblem setup the sanbox... any can help me!! i need test/simulate the purchase :(

Answer (score 0):

Check that you followed all steps described by this tutorial :

http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/

Hope this helps,
Vincent